# Help calculating intersection and unions of sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

[image]

> Let $N \ge 0$ be a natural number. What is $\bigcup_{n=1}^N [-n,n]$? What is $\bigcap_{n=1}^N [-n,n]$?

For the Union, is it just all the sets [-1, 1], [-2, 2] ... [-N, N]?

and for the intersection, is it the empty set?

Comment: This was also asked here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1434159/calculate-following-intersection-and-union-of-sets

Answer (score 2):

For the union you must consider the union of $[-1,1],[-2,2],\dots[-N,N]$ as you said. This is nothing but $[-N,N]$. For the intersection note that $[-1,1]$ is precisely the set which is contained in each of the sets in question and hence the intersection is $[-1,1]$.